# HQL how to query ElementCollection of String

Tags: java, hibernate, jdbc, hql

I have class like

```
public User{
   Long id;
   Set<String> roles;
}
```

How do I query all `User` objects with the role of `"ADMIN"`

**EDIT:**

I'm using Hibernate 3.0.5. And have tried most of the obvious approaches.

`from Users where roles in('ADMIN')` gives a JDBC error.
`from Users u where u.roles in('ADMIN')` gives a class cast exception

I think this may be a problem with this particular version of hibernate.

Comment: do you have a `Role` entity? How is the role a set of Strings? how are you mapping it. is the variable roles a transient variable.? Should nt the entity be like this `public User{
   Long id;
   Set<Role> roles;
}
`?

Comment: This is not an actual model. It is a example of the scenario in which I want to write my HQL query. This was the first thing that came to my mind so I made the example from those. The data types are correct...

Answer (score 29, accepted):

I've found solution:

```
"from User as user where 'ADMIN' in elements(user.roles)";
```

Somehow hql function value() have to help with this, you can also experiment with it, but that hql query above works for me.

Comment: This should be the chosen answer, as the other changes the model from Set<String> without even acknowledging it.

Comment: thx a lot,i have searched many answers.this is the only right one

Comment: great answer, old but gold

Comment: Hi, what if I wanna use like query? for example, I wanna something like `"from User as user where '%DMI%' in elements(user.roles)";`, but that doesn't work.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the query below

```
"from User as user where user.id in (select user.id from Role as role left join role.user as user where role.name = 'ADMIN')"
```

Answer (score -3):

This should do it:

```
session.createQuery("from User where roles in ('ADMIN')");
```